# uvm_monitor - does not sample correctly. Where am I wrong?

Tags: sampling, uvm

I have the following interface and uvm_monitor (run_phase shown below).

The DUT signals are "x" for sometime. When I print the signals, in my monitor, they are captured as "x". Great.

Next, DUT signals show a valid value (the first time). When I print the signals, in my monitor, they are captured as with valid values. Great.

Next, DUT updates the all the three signals to the next value, and at time stamp 134, mirror_byte_wr_en **remains to be 0 but expected to be at 0xffff.**.

Any idea, why? Appreciate your thoughts and inputs.

Example output from the log:

> UVM_INFO snp_decomp_snpd_egress_monitor.sv(65) @ 122:
>   uvm_test_top.m_snp_decomp_env.snpd_egress[0].m_monitor
>   [snp_decomp_snpd_egress_monitor] mirror_data =
>   0x00006c61776e694720616669617a7548
>
> UVM_INFO snp_decomp_snpd_egress_monitor.sv(71) @ 122:
>   uvm_test_top.m_snp_decomp_env.snpd_egress[0].m_monitor
>   [snp_decomp_snpd_egress_monitor] mirror_byte_wr_en = 0xffff
>
> UVM_INFO snp_decomp_snpd_egress_monitor.sv(76) @ 122:
>   uvm_test_top.m_snp_decomp_env.snpd_egress[0].m_monitor
>   [snp_decomp_snpd_egress_monitor] mirror_wr_addr = 0x00000
>
> UVM_INFO snp_decomp_snpd_egress_monitor.sv(65) @ 134:
>   uvm_test_top.m_snp_decomp_env.snpd_egress[0].m_monitor
>   [snp_decomp_snpd_egress_monitor]  mirror_data =
>   0x3c10xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx616c00000000
>
> UVM_INFO snp_decomp_snpd_egress_monitor.sv(71) @ 134:
>   uvm_test_top.m_snp_decomp_env.snpd_egress[0].m_monitor
>   [snp_decomp_snpd_egress_monitor]  mirror_byte_wr_en = **0x0000**
>
> UVM_INFO snp_decomp_snpd_egress_monitor.sv(76) @ 134:
>   uvm_test_top.m_snp_decomp_env.snpd_egress[0].m_monitor
>   [snp_decomp_snpd_egress_monitor]  mirror_wr_addr = 0x00010

```
enter code here
task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    snp_decomp_snpd_egress_transaction tr; 
    tr = snp_decomp_snpd_egress_transaction ::type_id::create("tr");
    forever begin
      @(vif.egress.egress_cb);
      fork
        begin
//          @ (vif.egress.egress_cb);
          tr.mirror_data = vif.egress.egress_cb.mirror_wr_data;
          `uvm_info(get_type_name(),$sformatf("mirror_data = 0x%x\n", vif.egress.egress_cb.mirror_wr_data),UVM_LOW); 
        end

        begin
//          @ (vif.egress.egress_cb);
          tr.mirror_wr_byte_en = vif.egress.egress_cb.mirror_byte_wr_en;
          `uvm_info(get_type_name(),$sformatf("mirror_byte_wr_en = 0x%x\n", vif.egress.egress_cb.mirror_byte_wr_en),UVM_LOW); 
    end
    begin
//          @ (vif.egress.egress_cb);
          tr.mirror_wr_addr = vif.egress.egress_cb.mirror_wr_addr;
          `uvm_info(get_type_name(),$sformatf("mirror_wr_addr = 0x%x\n", vif.egress.egress_cb.mirror_wr_addr),UVM_LOW); 
    end
      join
   end
endtask : run_phase




interface snp_decomp_snpd_egress_intf(input logic clock, input logic reset);



  logic [127:0] mirror_wr_data;
  logic [15:0]  mirror_byte_wr_en;
  logic  [18:0] mirror_wr_addr;


  modport DUT (

    input   clock,
    input   reset,          


    output  mirror_wr_data,
    output  mirror_byte_wr_en,
    output  mirror_wr_addr

    );  // modport DUT

  clocking  egress_cb @(posedge clock);


    input  mirror_wr_data;
    input  mirror_byte_wr_en;
    input  mirror_wr_addr;


  endclocking:  egress_cb

  modport  egress(clocking  egress_cb);

endinterface : snp_decomp_snpd_egress_intf
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbS7a.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is correct behaviour because sample values in clocking block were taken from the previous clock cycle. It depends on SystemVerilog time step semantics.

```
begin
  @(vif.egress.egress_cb);
  `uvm_info(get_type_name(), $sformatf("mirror_byte_wr_en: value from previous cycle - 'h%0h, value from current cycle - 'h%0h",
                                        vif.egress.egress_cb.mirror_byte_wr_en, vif.egress.mirror_byte_wr_en), UVM_LOW)
end
```

For full understanding - LRM 14.13.
Best regards, Maksim.